# Getting latest data out from a table and then doing a sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is logging some application data.

It's structured like

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

data

```
INSERT INTO `log` (`id`, `website_id`, `created_at`, `date`, `pages`)
VALUES
    (1,1,'2014-04-03 00:30:01','2014-04-03',30),
    (2,2,'2014-04-03 12:21:54','2014-04-03',13),
    (3,1,'2014-04-04 01:10:12','2014-04-04',40),
    (4,2,'2014-04-04 01:11:53','2014-04-04',20),
    (5,1,'2014-04-04 02:43:31','2014-04-04',5),
    (6,1,'2014-04-05 12:29:48','2014-04-05',8),
    (7,1,'2014-04-05 13:48:51','2014-04-05',0),
    (8,2,'2014-04-05 14:01:26','2014-04-05',20),
    (9,2,'2014-04-05 15:51:01','2014-04-05',30),
    (10,3,'2014-04-05 17:29:30','2014-04-05',15);
```

What I want to do is pull out the latest record for the day for each website, and then perform a sum on that so I get an overall count of the pages column.

So would expect 3 rows

```
2014-04-03 | 43
2014-04-04 | 25
2014-04-05 | 45
```

So when getting the row for the website it needs to get the row with the newest created first, so here

```
(6,1,'2014-04-05 12:29:48','2014-04-05',8),
(7,1,'2014-04-05 13:48:51','2014-04-05',0),
```

id 7 would be used, since it's newer. **So for 2014-04-05 website id 1 will have a page count of 0, not 8**

```
select date, sum(pages) from log group by date
```

result

```
2014-04-03 | 43
2014-04-04 | 65
2014-04-05 | 73
```

its way out since it doesn't filter, but Im not sure how to filter this.

Comment: you mean `order by date desc`? your sum() query already seems to do what you want - the total of all the `pages` fields, separated into individual days.

Comment: I not sure what you are trying to filter.  The query you have will produce exactly the results you need.

Comment: Hello, from my question "What I want to do is pull out the latest record for the day for each website" - my query above just sums all the date. Please re-read the question.. if there are two entires for a website on 1 day, then only the newest record should be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT L1.`date`, SUM(L1.`pages`) `pages`
FROM `log` L1
JOIN
(
  SELECT `website_id`, MAX(`created_at`) as `created_at`
  FROM `log`
  GROUP BY `website_id`, `date`
) L2
ON L1.`website_id` = L2.`website_id`
  AND L1.`created_at` = L2.`created_at`
GROUP BY `date`
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37b90/4)**

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, it is often fastest to find the most recent record using `not exists`.  The following will work best with an index on `log(website_id, date, created_at)`:

```
select l.date, sum(l.pages)
from log l
where not exists (select 1
                  from log l2
                  where l2.website_id = l.website_id and
                        l2.date = l.date and
                        l2.created_at > l.created_at
                 )
group by l.date;
```

Comment: Hi, This only seems to get me 1 row back, for 2014-04-05. However there show be a row for each date (see the expected from the question)

Comment: @Wizzard . . . Sorry about that.  I missed that you want the most recent on each day rather than the most recent in general.